# Web API application restricts to access the files from local physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-access

Using my local Web API application, I am trying to access the files that is available in the physical path of my system (D:/FileExplorerContent/). But it throws following error message.
"System.ArgumentException, 'D:/FileExplorerContent/' is not accessible. Access is denied."
Also I have provided full permission to the folder (D:/FileExplorerContent/). 
[image]

Still same problem exist. If I try to access same files that is available in 'D:/FileExplorerContent/' directory using my local MVC application, its working fine. 
I think my Web API application only restrict to access the files that is available in my local physical path (D:/FileExplorerContent/). How to solve this problem, could you please provide any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the IIS_IUSRS to that folder and set the permissions.

Comment: could you please provide steps to add "IIS_IUSRS" to that folder?

Comment: On your screenshot click the edit button -> in the next dialog click add -> type IIS_IUSRS in the textbox and hit the button check name. After that the IIS_IUSRS should be underlined -> press OK -> IIS_IUSRS should appear under "Group or user names" -> click on IIS_IURS and check the ckeckboxes "Read & Execute", "List folder contents" and "Read" and if necessary "Modify" -> press OK